# What is the limitation of Biosocial Theory developed by Linehan?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, stress, psychology

Linehan's biosocial theory takes into consideration of the accumulation effect of a stress on individuals, which the Diathesis-stress model could not explain. A predisposition (diathesis) with stress may cause a person to be suicidal but the accumulation effect makes the Biosocial model even more persuasive and sound. However, there is always something that a model or theory leaves out. What is it that the Biosocial theory does not explain?